# Two similar limits

Tags: limits

I have to find $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac {1^2+2^2+3^2 +\cdots+x^2}{x^2} - \frac {x} {3}$$ and $$ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac {1+2+3+\cdots+x}{x+2}- \frac{x}{2}.$$

I can tell that they have a similar solution but where to start?

Comment: At which point?

Comment: x is an integer????????

Comment: @superbass: Please use latex.It's difficult to understand what your question is.

Comment: Perhaps where to start is with a formula for $1+2+3+\cdots+x$. Do you know how to find the sum of an arithmetic progression?

Answer (score 1):

Considering x is an integer and limit at $\infty$. We can do it in this way, we know $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{x}n^2=\frac{x(x+1)(2x+1)}{6}\Rightarrow \displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{x}n^2/x^2-x/3=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x(x+1)(2x+1)}{6x^2}-x/3=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x(x+1)(2x+1)-2x^3}{6x^2}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3x^2+x}{6x^2}=\frac{1}{2}+\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{6x}=\frac {1}{2}$$                                                          2nd one can also be done similarly.

Comment: the result should be 1..

Comment: @superbass For the first one or the second one?  Because as far as I can see, there are no mistakes.

Comment: @superbass, none of the two given limits is 1: the first one is 0.5 and the second one is -0.5 ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to know the exact formula for the sum of the first $n$ squares to solve the first point. Consider:
$$ a_n = 1+\ldots+n^2-\frac{n^3}{3}. $$
You have:
$$ a_{n+1} - a_n = (n+1)^2 - \frac{(n+1)^3-n^3}{3} = n-\frac{2}{3}$$
and $a_1=\frac{2}{3}$, so:
$$ a_{n+1} = (a_{n+1}-a_n)+\ldots+(a_2-a_1)+a_1 = \sum_{j=1}^{n}j +O(n) = \frac{n^2}{2}+O(n), $$
and
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^2}=\frac{1}{2}.$$